# Maximize button missing from form dialog boxes on SharePoint 2013 (patched up to 8/18/2017)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, modal-dialog, forms-7

I posted in an older post but am concerned the information might be outdated so I wanted to create a new question.

I'm using the following script in hopes to add the maximize button back to every and all forms.

I want to use the default out of the box functionality so the goal is to be able to just click new item, edit item, or link to item and have the maximize button show on the default forms.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function maximizeWindow() { 
      var currentDialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog();
      if (currentDialog != null && !currentDialog.$1H_0) { 
          currentDialog.$1Y_0(); 
      }
    } 
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(maximizeWindow, 'sp.ui.dialog.js'); 
    </script>
```

I'm obviously missing something because after adding this to a script editor web part on the main page, the list web part still doesn't show the maximize button.

Any ideas what I'm missing?